# Installing a package from an older distribution

Tags: apt

I want to install libgnome-keyring0 on Ubuntu 22.04. However, it is not supported in this version. Instead, I've found a suggestion to install it from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libgnome-keyring0
I'm not sure how to use the link to install this library using apt.

Thank you

Comment: [libgnome-keyring is depreciated](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/libgnome-keyring) and [Ubuntu Bionic is end of standard support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). You could still build libgnome-keyring  from source I guess…

Comment: It's a website, not an apt repository. Apt cannot download from that website; it does not know how. You can download packages manually, then tell apt where to find them on your local system. It's all in the manpages.

Comment: @Zatigem I'm aware that it's unsupported but I have another package that depends on it. I actually did build it from source and seemingly installed it yet apt still complains that it's a missing dependency.

Comment: @user535733 I understand that, yet I couldn't find the actual URL to download the package file manually.

Comment: The URL in your question is not valid - it leads to a 404 page.